# Build fails when adding cordova plugin to Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but my reserch on this topic did not result in a solution that worked for me.

I am trying to port a web-app that was devoloped and build with cordova cli, into a microsoft visual studio project with the new community edition. (using the multi-device-hybrid-apps extension for visual studio)

The plugins that i want to use:

- org.apache.cordova.battery-status
- org.apache.cordova.device
- org.apache.cordova.globalization
- org.bcsphere.bluetooth
- a plugin that i created by my own
- org.stereolux.cordova.serial

All works well untill i try to import a usb-serial-plugin that i was using before.
https://github.com/stereolux/cordovarduino

But now unfortunally the build always fails with "Command failed with exit code 8" error during build.bat.

What ive already tried:

- defined the three environment variables correctly (ADT_HOME,JAVA_HOME,ANT_HOME)
- delete the bld folder inside the project
- clear cordova cache (inside visual studio settings)
- update all nessesary packages with the SDK Manager
- change to a project path without spaces

I dont know how to fix this problem and hope someone here can help me.

EDIT: Some details when i try to build the bld/Debug with Cordova CLI

> BUILD FAILED
>   D:\Android SDK\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\Android SDK\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> Total time: 4 seconds
>
> D:\VSCE2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp\BlankCordovaApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android
>   \cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^
>   Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\VSCE2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp\BlankCordovaApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir
>   =ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
>   Error: D:\VSCE2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp\BlankCordovaApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\wunderlichhe.WORKGROUP.000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)

Comment: Give more of a stack trace please.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur ive edit the initial post

Comment: You say your error about Visual Studio but stack trace shows android. Try to isolate your error. For example remove platforms/android, platforms/wp8 directories  and try to build

Comment: @AtillaOzgur thats because visual studio dont show me any details from the build process

Comment: Which platform are you trying to build windows8 or wp8? Which command you are using to build your app? "phonegap local run wp8" or "phonegap local run windows8"

Comment: @AtillaOzgur No i trying to build an android app. No other platform is needed.

Comment: Share the build output window message. Go to Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build and Run and then change build output verbosity = detailed. Build the project and share the build output window message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the plugin README.md, you can see this:

#### Install it

From the root folder of your cordova project, run :

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/stereolux/cordovarduino.git
cp plugins/org.stereolux.cordova.serial/lib/usbseriallibrary.jar platforms/android/libs`

If you are using the VS Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3 released last week then these steps will fix your issue:

copy this file: plugins\org.stereolux.cordova.serial\lib\usbseriallibrary.jar

into: res\native\android\libs\usbseriallibrary.jar

Build will succeed after that